# NSTableView's makeViewWithIdentifier finding nil on one of its child views

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have an NSTableView with two columns, one with a non-editable NSTextField and the other with an editable one. Each cell has a different identifier ("Camera" for the first column, "Position" for the other).

I am having no trouble with the first column's cell, however, the second one ("Position") finds nil when trying to access its editable NSTextField. I have tried using only one identifier. Declaring it at the beginning of viewForTableColumn, and several other things, but it keeps missing that NSTextField. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

My Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    if tableColumn?.identifier == "Column0" {
        let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("Camera", owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView
        cell?.textField?.stringValue = Array(cameraOrder.keys)[row]
        return cell

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("Position", owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView
        cell!.textField!.stringValue = String(Array(cameraOrder.values)[row]) //THIS ONE IS FINDING NIL
        return cell
    }
}
```

My Views:

[image: Views Structure]

Comment: Did you check the connection?

Answer (score -1):

I found I way to do it, although I don't know if its optimal:

It seems that having two textFields was for some reason making my code crash. I am using only the identifier of the first column ("Camera") and taking modifying its label to fit my needs. What ends up happening, is that an instance of the first text field is created in my second column cell, but it has the properties I need.

```
let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("Camera", owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView
//...SET UP OF FIRST COLUMN, AND THEN WITHOUT CHANGING IDENTIFIERS..//
cell?.textField?.delegate = self
cell?.textField!.placeholderString = "Position Here"
cell!.textField!.editable = true
cell!.textField!.stringValue = String(Array(cameraOrder.values)[row])
return cell
```

Comment: If you don't know if this is a good answer, don't post it. Give us some time to answer.

Comment: @Willeke I didn't mark it as accepted precisely to give others a chance. Would you consider removing the negative mark?